# windows 10 listitem with checkbox

Tags: windows-phone

i have one Restfulservice. when i call that service it gives the items with checkbox. after display the items. user selects some items and click on save. i have to send that information to db via the restful services.

can u please tell..

1) how to display the items from webservice [columns and rows] .

```
 itemname         selected or unselected

 item1                 []
 item2                 []
 item3                 []
```

2) how to send the selected or unselected items back to db via restful services.

Answer (score 0):

1) XAML Example:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel>
                     <RadioButton 
                                  DataContext="{Binding }"  
                                  Content="{Binding Label}" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                                  x:Name="radioButton"
                                  GroupName="SomeGroupName"
                                   />     
                   </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

DTO:

ListItem is a list for items XD.
Items its like:

```
Public class items
{
     public string label {get ; set;}
     public bool IsChecked {get; set;}
}
```

2)Use Json for send and recive data.

Comment: i will get the column names also from restful service.

Comment: Yes!! in this exaple , the label is sending  in "label" field.